# portability of windows 8 phone library to wp 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8, compatibility, windows-8.1, class-library

I have a windows phone class library built using the WP8...**Is it possible to upgrade this library to support WP 8.1?** If yes how can it be done using visual studio 2013?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would strongly suggest to create a new Portable Class Library instead of a Class Library. Theese PCLs can then be used in Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows 8.1 Projects.

If the Library worked on Windows Phone 8, you should be able to simply copy over the code from the Class Library to the PCL.

Comment: Do i just need to copy over the code to a PCL? Do i have to do something else also in visual studio to support WP 8.1?

Comment: Will this library be compatible with the windows phone 7.5 and 7.8 as well?

Comment: It depends on the target that you specify. If I am not mistaken, you should be able to select Windows Phone 7.5 (which is 7.8) as target for the PCL

Comment: I tried to copy the code from the phone class library to portable class library but some but xaml files and their corresponding .cs files throw errors..Ex: using System.Windows.Controls statement is throwing error...In references I checked that the only assembly included is .NET Portable Subset.. So windows phone API's cannot be used in PCL's?

Comment: Per default, it does not know what to do with this code as some Windows Phone APIs are not in the normal .net package. If you are using a Phone specific API you have to encapsule this code with 

#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
//Code goes here 
#endif

Answer (score 0):

Depends on if you want to use it with Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 or Windows Phone 8.1 (XAML).

For Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 you do not need to do anything, you can reference your WP8 lib from a Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 without any problems. You can upgrade it to 8.1 in Visual Studio (right click on project and Retarget to Windows Phone 8.1).

You cannot use a WP8 lib with Windows Phone 8.1 (XAML) app and you cannot upgrade it to be used with Windows Phone 8.1 (XAML), you need to create a new one a copy and paste parts that work with Windows Phone 8.1 (XAML).

Comment: I want to use it with WP 8.1(XAML).. Can it not be used even in case of a portable library?

Comment: you can convert it to a PCL, if has no windows phone specific stuff